# Mixing django-filepicker and mongodb

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine, filepicker.io, filepicker

I'm developing a django 1.4 application, and I'm using [django-filepicker](https://github.com/Filepicker/django-filepicker) to upload images. They use a special modelField for images called FPFileField.

I'm interested in storing those images in a MongoDB database, instead of uploading it to a "media" folder or something similar.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

I've tried mongoengine with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend storing the url into your mongo Document directly and then making use of the filepicker.io URL and built in S3 support rather than storing the file on your servers directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#when-should-i-use-gridfs)

I'd also consider uploading it to amazon's [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) service too - depending on what your requirements are.